# Docker - Unable to set password for Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have been trying to login to the postgres Django administration through localhost:8000, and i've tried multiple solutions from SO but failed.

**This is my docker-compose.yml file ---**

```
# docker_tutorial/docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:

  database:
    image: postgres:12.7-alpine
    volumes:
        - ./backup_data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
        - DJANGO_ENV=production
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  backend:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - ./backend:/app/backend
    - ./server:/app/server
    - ./requirements.txt:/app/requirements.txt
    - ./manage.py:/app/manage.py
    depends_on:
      - database
  
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/opt/web
    depends_on:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 80:80
  
  nginx_backend_server:
    build: ./nginx_backend_server
    ports:
        - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
        - backend
```

**This is my settings.py DATABASE --**

```
      if os.getenv('DJANGO_ENV') == 'production':
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'postgres',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
            'HOST': 'database',
            'PORT': 5432,
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
```

Whenever i try to login, i set the message as `Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.` eventhough i've set the PASSWORD and USER as `postgres`. Can anyone help?

Comment: I hope these are your env configruations for django application `DJANGO_ENV=production, POSTGRES_DB=postgres, POSTGRES_USER=postgres, POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres`. But you have added this with `database` service, actually it should be with `backend`. Also see [How to extend this image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) at postgresql docker for the env variables for `postgresql` image

Comment: Thankyou for the reply @PRATHEESHPC .. i did what you said but now im getting an error `OperationalError at /admin/login/
connection to server at "database" (192.168.32.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
 Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

Comment: Please update the question with the changes you made.

Comment: On the image you use `listen_addresses` is not modified. Probably, you need to edit it. Then, you might get pg_hba rules error. You need to edit that one too if you are using default settings for that image, `postgres:12.7-alpine`.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN the listen_address is already set to `*`